# Sum of array list using class with multiple elements java

Tags: java, list

I have a class like this

```
public class SellableItems {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public SellableItems() {
    }

    }
    // getters and setters here
}
```

Now lets say I have created some objects and put them into an `ArrayList`, which looks like this

```
List<SellableItems> table1 = Main.readFromTable1();
```

Then goes my question. How do calculate the sum (the price) of the `ArrayList`?

Comment: Just a note, it's the recommended format to *not* start variable names with capital letters as you do with `Table1`. As you can see, even the SO thinks it's a type and is highlighting it teal.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I have updated my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `List` is a list of `Integers` you can use something like:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int ListItm : DataList) {
    sum += ListItm;
}
```

Otherwise apply necessary adaptations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can do it very easily with streams:

```
List<SellAbleItems> table1 = Main.readFromTable1();

double sum = table1.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e.getPrice()).sum();
// use your sum
```

Comment: @PeterHoldensgaard please consider accepting this answer then. It is 1:1 the same as the one you accepted but it was posted an hour earlier

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Assuming that I did this using a string as sum, could I then print out all the names from table1?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to *reduce* the list to a `double` value, to do so, you have to iterate over the `Table1` and in each iteration add the price value to the `sum` variable:

```
double sum = 0d;
for(SellAbleItems s : Table1) 
     sum += s.getPrice();
```

Comment: So this is just a foreach loop and adding all the entries together to the double sum?

Comment: @PeterHoldensgaard yes.